# Find 101 in prime numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm currently solving a problem which is pretty straightforward: I need to find all prime numbers up to N which contain 101 in them and count them.
Say if N is 1000 then the output should ne 6 since there is 101, 1013, 1015, 5101, 6101 and 8101. I used sieve's algorithm to get all of the prime numbers up to N, though  I don't know how could I solve it completely. I thought of std::find, but resigned from that idea because the time complexity grows fast. I know I need to modify sieve's algorithm to fit my needs though I can't find any patterns. 
Any help would be appreciated.
Edit:
I'm using this algorithm:

```
vector<int> sieve;
vector<int> primes;

for (int i = 1; i < max + 1; ++i)
   sieve.push_back(i);   // you'll     learn more efficient ways to handle this later
sieve[0]=0;
for (int i = 2; i < max + 1; ++i) {   // there are lots of brace styles, this is mine
   if (sieve[i-1] != 0) {
      primes.push_back(sieve[i-1]);
      for (int j = 2 * sieve[i-1]; j < max + 1; j += sieve[i-1]) {
          sieve[j-1] = 0;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: So you have a list of candidate numbers, and you want to keep only those with a substring "101"  in their decimal representation? Or you want to change the initial sieve? Or what?

Comment: Use sieve to find *all* the primes, convert to text (with `std::to_string`), and use `find` to check for `"101"`

Comment: your question needs to be improved (not really clear what is the question, other than debugging, which you should do before asking). Anyhow your solution can be made much more efficient by checking only for those numbers that contain `101` whether they are prime

Comment: Your sieve will go faster if you change the inner loop to "`for (int j =  sieve[i-1] * sieve[i-1]; j < max + 1; j += sieve[i-1]) {`".  It will go twice as fast if you change the outer loop to `for (int i = 3; i < max + 1; i+=2)` (that will only find odd primes, but the only even prime doesn't contain "101").  If you make this change, you should change  the inner loop to `... j += 2*sieve[i-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, checking every prime number for containing "101" is a waste of time. Generating all numbers containing 101 and checking whether they are prime is probably faster.

For generating the 101 numbers, let's look at the possible digit patterns, e.g. with 5 digits:

- nn101
- n101m
- 101mm

For each of these patterns, you get all the numbers by iterating `n` in an outer loop and `m` in an inner loop and doing the math to get the pattern's value (of course, you need not consider even `m` values, because the only even prime is 2). You are done when the values reaches `N`.

To check for being a prime, an easy way is to prepare a list of all primes up to `M=sqrt(N)`, using a sieve if you like, and check whether your value is divisible by one of them.

This should be running in `O(N^1.5)`. Why? The number of patterns grows with `O(logN)`, the iterations inside each pattern with `N/1000`, giving `O(N)`, the prime check with the number of primes up to `M`, being `O(M/log(M))`, finding these primes with a sieve being `O(M^2)`. Altogether that's `O(N * log(N) * sqrt(N) / log(sqrt(N)) + N)` or `O(N^1.5)`.

Comment: Woah, I didn't even think of that, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify your prime generation algorithm. When processing the primes you get from your gen alg you just have to check if the prime satisfies your condition:

e.g.

```
// p is the prime number
if (contains(p))
{
   // print or write to file or whatever
}
```

with:

```
bool contains(int);
```

a function which checks your condition

Comment: That would mean I'm checking every prime number, I'm trying to find a way which would give out the primes on the first go

Comment: @JacobStn. when you find that algorithm write a PHD about it

Comment: @JacobStn. I don't think you can avoid checking every prime number.  If you are going to use a sieve, you need to find every prime (up to root N anyway) in order to find the other primes.  For "small" values of N, a sieve will be "fast enough", for "medium" (say 2^64) you will need  a better sieve (holding 8 bits per byte, and not storing the even values at all), for "large" values of N (2^512), the question becomes uninteresting - most primes will contain "101" somewhere.